# Add a sibling div to Ember Form For input element

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am using [Ember Form For](http://martndemus.github.io/ember-form-for) and I want to know if it is possible to add a sibling element.

Currently doing this: `{{f.radio-field "gender" "female"}}`

will render this:

```
<div>
  <label><input type="radio" value="female" />Female</label>
</div>
```

I need a container sibling element which I can add CSS pseudo classes to. I am unable to target parent containers of the input hence why I need a sibling element.
So something like this is what I am after:

```
<div>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" value="female" />
    Female
    <div class="someClass></div>
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't look possible (at least for the radio-field component). See here: https://github.com/martndemus/ember-form-for/blob/master/addon/templates/components/form-fields/radio-field.hbs. The addon only renders the control (input element) and the label's text. The only way to add that would be to do so programmatically in `didInsertElement` or some other way.

Comment: I wonder, why people use such plugins at all? It just limits you, imho

Comment: Yeah this was an executive decision

Answer (score 1):

### Updated answer

This addon seems to have support for custom components, it could be found in [old docs](https://github.com/martndemus/ember-form-for/tree/1.4.1#custom-fields) and in source code

### Old answer (probably wouldn't work properly for this specific addon)

Theoretically, it should be possible to create your own component (i.e. `my-radio-field`) by extending https://github.com/martndemus/ember-form-for/blob/master/addon/components/form-fields/radio-field.js and replacing `layout`

Component code:

```
import Component from 'ember-form-for/components/form-fields/radio-field';
import layout from 'my-project-name/templates/components/my-radio-field';

export default Component.extend({layout});
```

Template:

```
{{#form-field propertyName
    class="radio-field"
    classNames=fieldClasses
    errorClasses=errorClasses
    hintClasses=hintClasses
    inputClasses=inputClasses
    labelClasses=labelClasses
    object=object
    hint=hint
    form=form
    label=labelText
    control=control
    update=(action update) as |f|}}
  {{#f.label required=required}}
    {{f.control
        option=value
        accesskey=accesskey
        autocomplete=autocomplete
        autofocus=autofocus
        autosave=autosave
        dir=dir
        disabled=disabled
        hidden=hidden
        lang=lang
        list=list
        required=required
        tabindex=tabindex
        title=title
    }}
    {{f.labelText}}
    <div>Hello world</div>
  {{/f.label}}
  {{f.errors}}
  {{f.hint}}
{{/form-field}}
```

Comment: Thanks that sounds really promising. I'll give it a go.